# Passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' error / expected 'const' char*' but argument is of type 'int'

Tags: c, file-io, struct

I come today with general concern for my program. I've been putting a good amount of my time (time that I could use studying for finals) on this one program, and I feel like I need to step back from it for a bit. The program tells me these errors when I attempt to run it.

```
lines 115, 120, 131, 136, 146:
  warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast
  note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'int'
```

(note that this is a work in progress, and not really meant to be TOO functional, but if you see anything else, let me know)

My class has a very... interesting professor who teaches in a similarly interesting way, so I've had trouble attempting to understand some of the aspects of this programs requirements. Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ITEMS 1000


struct drink {
int drinkNum;
double drinkPrice;
}drinklist[10];

struct items {
double itemPrice;
};

struct raffle {
double rafValue;
};

int main(){
double preTickets, doorTickets, minBid;
int preSold, numItems, rafTickets = 0, rafPrizes, rafCost;

int i, numEvents, x;

FILE* fin;
fin = fopen("input.txt", "r");

// Line#1 from input file
fscanf(fin, "%lf %lf %d", &preTickets, &doorTickets, &preSold);

// Line#2 from input file
fscanf(fin, "%d %lf", &numItems, &minBid);

// This allocates space for the list of auction items dynamically. 

struct items* itemList = (struct items*)malloc(sizeof(struct items)*numItems);

// Line#3 from input file.
for(i = 0; i < numItems; i++){
    fscanf(fin, "%lf", &itemList[i].itemPrice);
}

// Line#4 fron input file.
fscanf(fin, "%d %d %d", &rafTickets, &rafCost, &rafPrizes);

// Same as the itemList. Creates enough space for the number of raffle prizes you need.
struct raffle* raffleList = (struct raffle*)malloc(sizeof(struct raffle)*rafPrizes);


// Line#5 from input file
for(i = 0; i < rafPrizes; i++){
    fscanf(fin, "%lf", &raffleList[i].rafValue);
}

struct drink drinklist[10];

// Line#6 from input file
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    fscanf(fin, "%d", &drinklist[i].drinkNum);
}

 // Line#7 from input file
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    fscanf(fin, "%lf", &drinklist[i].drinkPrice);
}

// This just prints out the output that has been read in so far.
// This will also show you how you can refer to the different members of data that you need later.
printf("%.2lf %.2lf %d\n", preTickets, doorTickets, preSold);
printf("%d %.2lf\n", numItems, minBid);

for(i = 0; i < numItems; i++){
    printf("%.2lf ", itemList[i].itemPrice);
}

printf("\n%d %d %d\n", rafTickets, rafCost, rafPrizes);

for(i = 0; i < rafPrizes; i++){
    printf("%.2lf ", raffleList[i].rafValue);
}

printf("\n");
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf("%d ", drinklist[i].drinkNum);
}
printf("\n");
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf("%.2lf ", drinklist[i].drinkPrice);
}
printf("\n");

// This frees the memory that you allocated dynamically.
free(itemList);
free(raffleList);


// loop that runs from from 0 to < numCommands and read in each command and evaluate it.

fscanf(fin, "%d", &numEvents);
fclose(fin);

int actLoop, boughtTickets, boughtRaffle, boughtDrink;
int itemPrice, currentBid, guestBid, bidOffer;
int guestRaf;
int drinkWanted;

for (actLoop=0; actLoop<numEvents; actLoop++); {

int action;

fscanf(fin, "%s", action);

if (strcmp(action, "BUY TICKET") == 0) {
    fscanf(fin, "%d", boughtTickets);
    printf("Sold tickets %d - %d", &preSold+1, &preSold+boughtTickets);
}

else if (strcmp(action, "BIDITEM") == 0) {
    fscanf(fin, "%d%d%.2lf", &itemList[i], &guestBid, &bidOffer);

    if (bidOffer < itemList[i].itemPrice + minBid) {
        printf("Bid for item %d rejected for person %d at %.2lf", &itemList[i], &guestBid, &bidOffer);
    }
    else
        printf("Bid for item %d accepted for person %d at %.2lf", &itemList[i], &guestBid, &bidOffer);
        itemList[i].itemPrice == bidOffer;
}

else if (strcmp(action, "CLOSEAUCTION") == 0) {

}


else if (strcmp(action, "BUY RAFFLE") == 0) {
    fscanf(fin, "%d%d", &boughtRaffle, &guestRaf);
    if (boughtRaffle > rafTickets) {
        boughtRaffle == rafTickets;
        rafTickets = rafTickets - boughtRaffle;
    }
        printf("Raffle Tickets %d - %d given to person %d", &rafTickets, &rafTickets+boughtRaffle, &guestBid);

}

else if (strcmp(action, "BUY DRINK") == 0) {
    fscanf(fin, "%d%d", &drinkWanted, &drinklist[i].drinkNum);
    if (drinklist[i].drinkNum < drinkWanted) {
        drinkWanted = drinklist[i].drinkNum - drinkWanted;
    }
    printf("Sold %d of drink %d", &drinklist[i].drinkNum, &drinkWanted);
        drinklist[i].drinkNum = drinklist[i].drinkNum - drinkWanted;

}
}
}
```

Comment: int action;

fscanf(fin, "%s", action);

You are scanning a string into an integer.  `action` in this case is declared as the wrong type.  You need a character array to read into.

Comment: Please edit your question and remove all of the excessive code that has nothing to do with the question being asked. Expecting people to wade through the first 100+ lines to find the 8 or 10 that actually contain the problem and it's cause is pretty inconsiderate. Thanks.

Comment: Please learn what an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Complete Example](http://sscce.org/)) is.  What you provided is not.  The error message from the compiler is remarkably explicit; paraphrasing, _you should pass a `const char *` for argument 1 to `strcmp()` but you are passing an `int`._, along with line number information.  What more information could you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading a string into an `int`, you should use `char` array instead:

```
char action[200];
fscanf(fin, "%199s", action);
```

And here you need the address of `boughtTickets`

```
fscanf(fin, "%d", &boughtTickets);
```

Here you're printing the addresses of variables instead of their values:

```
printf("Sold tickets %d - %d", &preSold+1, &preSold+boughtTickets);
```

You get the idea, please read a good C book I recommend K&R.

Answer (score 1):

`strmp` compare string to another string but for your program you are comparing `int` (`action`) to string.

also for `fscanf(fin, "%s", action);` `fscanf` is reading string from the file input descriptor `fin` so the type of `action` should be char buffer

```
char action[256];

fscanf(fin, "%s", action);

if (strcmp(action, "BUY TICKET") == 0) {
```